# Show button only on certain page with Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have a general `Header.html` and `Header.js` that i use for all of my pages, Now some of my buttons show depending on user level which is all good but the issue i am having is that i only want to show this one button on only one specific page and it should not show anywhere else, Here is my code:

```
    <div class="pull-right" data-bind="tooltip: { title: DashboardEdit, placement: 'top' }">
    <button class="btn actionButtonIcon" id="DashboardEdit" data-bind="click: changeButtonText">
        <figure>
            <img src="../../../Images/NotesPink.png" />
            <figcaption data-bind="text: $data.ProcurementbuttonText() ? 'Save': 'Edit'"></figcaption>
        </figure>
    </button>
</div>

            self.ProcurementbuttonText = ko.observable(false);

        self.changeButtonText = function(){
         self.ProcurementbuttonText(!self.ProcurementbuttonText())

        }
```

Now i only want to show this button only if my user selects dashboard, if the user browses another place that uses my `header.html` i don't want this button to show there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can bind an observable/function that returns a boolean to the visible property.  like this `<button data-bind="visible: isVisible"></button>`.  then all you need to do is work out the conditions for the button to be visible or not.

```js
var vm = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.mode = ko.observable(false);
  self.DashboardEdit = ko.observable("Edit Dashboard");
  
  self.changeButtonText = function(){
    self.DashboardEdit("Edit Dashboard Changed");
    self.mode(!self.mode());
  }
  self.showDashboardButton = ko.observable(true);
  
  self.toggleDashboardButtonVisibility = function(){
    self.showDashboardButton(!self.showDashboardButton());
  }
  self.ProcurementbuttonText = ko.pureComputed(function(){
    return self.mode() ? 'Save' : 'Edit';
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="pull-right">
  <button class="btn actionButtonIcon" id="DashboardEdit" data-bind="click: changeButtonText, visible: showDashboardButton">
        <figure>
            <figcaption data-bind="text: $data.ProcurementbuttonText"></figcaption>
        </figure>
    </button>
</div>

<button data-bind="click: toggleDashboardButtonVisibility">Toggle Visibility</button>
```